# Reusable .xib + cocoa class components, how to auto size and style superview in storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa, xib

I have implemented reusable button component using combination of .xib and cocoa class following [**this guide**](https://developerslogblog.wordpress.com/2017/05/14/swiff-3-reusable-components-using-xib-files-and-the-interface-builder/)

It works, but there is an issue. In order to use it in one of my main View Storyboards I have to first drag in a normal view (referenced as superview in question title) and then apply my `Button` class, to make it a button.

This works, but initial view height and width alongside its white background persist, so I have to always manually rewrite those when I use my component, which in itself results in poor reusability.

Ideally, I'd like to drag in a view, set it to `Button` class and thats it, that view should instantly take buttons height and width and have transparent background. Is something like this achievable?

To light more context on this issue here are few useful bits of my implementation

**1. Reusable component made as a .xib view and its own cocoa class**

[image]

**2. Contents of `Button.swift`**

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class Button: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

  @IBInspectable var buttonLabel: String? {
    get {
      return label.text
    }
    set(buttonLabel) {
      label.text = buttonLabel
    }
  }

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    componentInit()
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    componentInit()
  }

  private func componentInit() {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: Button.self)
    bundle.loadNibNamed("Button", owner: self, options: nil)
    addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.frame = self.bounds
    contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
  }

}
```

**3. Example usage (inside one of my main view storyboards) demonstrating how ordinary view is turned into a button, but has issues with height, width and background color**

[image]

P.S ^ if its hard to tell what is going on in a gif above, I basically drag `UIView` into a story board and give it custom class attribute of `Button`, this turns that view into a button.

**EDIT:** Just to make it clearer, my question is: Can I apply width, height and transparent colour to my XIB's parent / super view? End goal here is to just drag in a view onto storyboard, give it custom class of a `Button` and thats it, it should be sized properly and have transparent background, as opposed to how it is at the moment (view doesn't get sized as button and has white background)

Comment: Just a guess: have you tried implementing the view's `intrinsicContentSize`?

Comment: @JamesBucanek Actually, I didn't. After reading the doc about it, it seems like a viable solution, but could you please expand? i.e. does this go onto parent view in main storyboard somehow? I am unable to find this option in size tools.

Comment: It was just a guess. `intrinsicContentSize` is a property of `UIView` that auto-layout uses to size a view. Auto-layout first queries a view for its intrinsic size and, in the absence of conflicting constraints, will size the view to match. Most controls (buttons, labels, ...) and many content views (image view, ...) have intrinsic sizes that allow them automatically resize themselves to match the size of their content. I haven't played with it, but I was hoping that the new-and-improved IB might use the intrinsic size to auto-size the view in the storyboard; auto-layout certain will.

Comment: `intrinsicContentSize` is indeed what your custom view is missing in order to provide self-derived dimensions, so you can override and return a size that can be dependant on your label's own `intrinsicContentSize` for example (so it would automatically grow for larger strings - you get the idea). Now the background can be easily set to `.clear` on your custom view. Having said that, if you plan to make heavy use of designables please bear in mind that IB (at least at this, v9.x, stage) can become really unstable & a nightmare to work with...

Comment: @Alladinian so, do I set `intrinsicContentSize` inside my `contentView` component or do I need to set it on a view that I drag into storyboard in the gif? Thats the one I need to size and clear the background, hence I'd need to somehow do all of this inside my designable so I just apply its class to any view an it works out of the box. Thank you for the warning on `IB`, this was preferred way of doing things as I am just starting

Comment: Can you want to add full-screen transparent color view between your xib and behind view?

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani not fullscreen but auto size it to match button edges. So right now this is how it works. `Button` xib has set width / height / and transparent background, its styled exactly how I need it.

I go to my `Main.storyboard` drag in a `UIView` (that white block you see in gif preview) and go to its properties to set "Custom Class" to be `Button`. This works partially, button is there now, but it still has incorrect width / height and white background. I want these to adjust at the time when I set "Custom Class"

Comment: Can you submit a demo project to github/bitbucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pin your subviews in *Button* properly and also in Main.storyboard. Then your custom view will autosize. And clear color is working.

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class Button: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    @IBInspectable
    var backColor: UIColor = .clear {
        didSet {
            backgroundColor = backColor
            contentView.backgroundColor = backColor
        }
    }

    override var backgroundColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            return backgroundColor
        } set {

        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var buttonLabel: String? {
        get {
            return label.text
        }
        set(buttonLabel) {
            label.text = buttonLabel
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        componentInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        componentInit()
    }

    private func componentInit() {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: Button.self)
        bundle.loadNibNamed("Button", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.frame = bounds
        backgroundColor = backColor
        contentView.backgroundColor = backColor
        contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        // for static height
        contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70).isActive = true
    }

}
```

To ensure you CustomView would size itself properly, you can use bottom constraint >= 0. After testing reset to equals.

[image]